# How can I use grep to find strings that match both of the conditions in cygwin?

Tags: unix, grep, cygwin

So I have a text file which is a list of people and some of their credentials. I need to grep for all the lines that have "2014" and "female" in them at the same time. I'm using cygwin for this so keep that in in mind. Thanks!

Comment: I assume that you mean that you don't know in advance, which of the two must occur earlier in the line?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pipe the output of the first grep as input to the second grep:

```
grep '2014' some_file.txt | grep 'female'
```